# Is this translation English to Chinese translation correct or close?

Tags: translation, word-choice, mandarin, meaning-in-context

An unprecedented look into the food and culture of ice, from Iceland's premier chef and the owner of Reykjavik's Restaurant Dill.

一个史无前例的食物和冰岛的文化，从冰岛总理厨师和雷克雅未克的所有者迪尔餐厅。

Comment: as it stands it means "unprecedented food and Iceland's culture", where is "look"？ "a look at" could be 看看。。。but then "unprecedented" together with "look"may have to become "taking an unprecedented look" 史无前例地一样子看看 （看一下， 看一眼），meaning of "from／从" seems obscure,      "sth. from..."  may be 来自...某事物／事情,owner of Restaurant Dill 迪尔餐厅的所有者，

Comment: for chef and owner being the same person (which  might be made clearer w/o "the") some users might suggest 兼：高级厨师兼。。。经理（所有者）

Comment: some users seem to have difficulty understanding the original English,"a look into from [person]" seems to sound somewhat strange (might expect "by" instead),users would like to thank user answering the question for incorporating suggestion to use 兼）

Comment: If it's a title of an article, the Chinese way to express it is: 冰島頂級大廚兼雷克雅未克Dill飯店老闆帶你以前所未有的視角切入冰島食物和文化

Answer (score 2):

- An unprecedented (一个前所未有的)
- look into  (探讨)
- the food and culture of Iceland (冰岛的食品与文化)
- from Iceland's premier chef and the owner of Reykjavik's Restaurant Dill (从冰岛顶级厨师兼雷克雅未克区的迪尔餐厅老板)

> Chinese grammar:
>
> 从冰岛顶级厨师兼雷克雅未克区的迪尔餐厅老板(的角度), (去作)  一个前所未有的, (对)冰岛食品与文化的探讨
>
> from Iceland's premier chef and the owner of Reykjavik's Restaurant Dill ('s point of view) (to take ) an unprecedented look into the food and culture of Iceland

*'premier' is not a noun here, it is an adjective for "leading"*

*The guy is a leading chef and he is also a restaurant owner*

*史无前例 usually referring to ground breaking/ historic event. A look into the food and culture of Iceland doesn't seem to fit the requirement. If America elected a gay or female president, that would qualify as 史无前例*

Answer (score 1):

An unprecedented look into the food and culture of ice, from Iceland's premier chef and the owner of Reykjavik's Restaurant Dill.

冰岛顶级大厨，同时也是位于雷克雅未克的饭店DILL的拥有者，对用冰做成的食物和冰文化作了一次前所未有的考察。